# Ошибка с удалением\редактированием базы

Tags: visual-basic

Доброго времени суток. Есть такая проблема: при удалении строки в базе через экзешник бьет следующую ошибку:

```
Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.
```

И я не знаю как это исправить... Впервые сталкиваюсь с такой ошибкой.

Вот код, который висит на кнопке "Удалить":

```
Private Sub Button14_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button14.Click
    UsersBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub
```

Код на сохранение изменений:

```
    Private Sub Button13_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button13.Click
    Me.Validate()
    Me.UsersBindingSource.EndEdit()
    Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.AdministratorDataSet)
End Sub
```

Т.е. работа тут идет не с сервером, а, так сказать, с локальной базой, которая находится в папке с экзешником.
Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Недостаточно информации в вопросе, попробуйте перестроить его, добавьте необходимую информацию.

Comment: Так... При добавлении новой строки в таблицу

       UsersBindingSource.AddNew()

все отлично добавляется и сохраняется. Но при удалении(RemuveCurrent()) сохранение не принимается(код сохранения указан выше).При изменении также не принимается, выбивает ошибку  

        Update requires a valid DeleteCommand when passed DataRow collection with deleted rows.


Ну, я  не знаю информацию еще можно добавить, вроде все что нужно добавил

Answer (score 2):

DeleteCommand это свойство SqlDataAdapter, которое используется при удалении данных.

Например, программно:
у вас lcDa типа SqlDataAdapter

```
lcDa.DeleteCommand = new SqlCommand("DELETE FROM bla-bla-bla",...);
```

Непрограммно можно команду удаления ввести прямо в свойство компонента SqlDataAdapter.
Почитайте у Microsofta  SqlDataAdapter.DeleteCommand, там должны быть примеры.

Comment: Спасибо за совет. Но мне не нужен сервер. У меня база локальная, лежит в папке рядом с сервером. Связываюсь с ней не SQl-запросами, а простым кодом. Чет не получается объяснить... Скажем так - перетаскиваю таблицу на форму, а на кнопки прописываю простенький код. Вот как-то так. Никаких запросов на SQL нету. И, если честно, я без понятия куда из вставить ;)

Comment: Ну и что, что база локальная. Это же база, запросы на более низком уровне всё равно отправляются SQL.

Comment: Я понимаю... Ноя потому и делаю локальную - потому что не очень дружу с запросами. К тому же раньше никогда такой ошибки не было, всегда работало. И я без понятие где и что прописать, чтобы исправить

Comment: а primary key есть у таблицы в кот. удаляете?

Comment: либо пишете комманду удаления сами, либо в таблице должен быть первичный ключ, и тогда при переносе таблицы на форму комманды select, update и delete создаются автоматически.

Comment: Первичный ключ есть